# Does a router recognize and re-route it's external IP?

Tags: router

Seems like it would be smarter to have the router recognize it's own IP, but I guess maybe always following the same protocol would be cleaner/more stable.

I just had this idea that I might test this out as well with the regular mail. Address a letter to myself, put stamps on it, and place it in my mailbox...lol.

So does anyone know for sure, if within my network, I have two computers and my router is configured to forward inbound request on port 80 to one, my webserver, and I try to access my external ip from the other computer (client), does the router recognize that it is about to send a request to itself and just keep the request, sending it straight to my server on my network, or does the request make it to my ISP, who then sends it back?

Comment: It is looking for a destination; it is adhering to the protocol. The ISP is nothing more than the loaner of the IP, the actual device is current owner.

Comment: Does it work then?  I know in the past at least, accessing a server from an internal computer, with router's external IP didn't work.  I heard routers have a new feature now.. don't recall the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a network request to an IP address, your computer typically broadcasts an `ARP` request to ask `'Who has this IP address?'`. The clients on the network then check their addresses and the one host that has the IP address then replies to the requesting host `'Oh! That's me!!'`. The request can the be routed to the appropriate host.

Because the "external" interface of the router has its public IP address assigned to it, when the network is asked `'Who has this IP?'`, the router looks at its addresses and replies `'Oh! That's me!!'` and takes the request from your host and, because of the requested port, uses its logic to then forward the request to the appropriate server.

What happens if no one on the network has the address? Well, that's what the `gateway` setting is for! When the host sees that the address is on a different network, it sends the request up to the host that is listed as the `gateway` and says `'Dunno where this goes, figure it out.'` This continues from router to router until either the `time to live (TTL)` or the `hop count` on the request run out, at which point the request is sent back as a failure.

Naturally all this happens **after** `DNS` resolution... provided the domain name resolves to a correct address. But that is for another answer.

Comment: this probably won't surprise you but just comment that I see that after arp -d, deleting te arp cache, tracert publicip still does 1ms and does it directly to the gateway.

Comment: @barlop that's what I said... lol

Answer (score 2):

Trace Route.

if you are in Windows, bring up a command prompt.  type "tracert" and your external IP.  You'll see it make one hop.  Should be a 1ms hop.  So, it doesn't go out to your ISP (1 hop) and then back to you (2nd hop).

Same thing if you tracert with the name of one of your computers on the network.